# backbone jquery debug chrome console keeps clearing the output

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to follow a simple backbone tutorial online. The problem is when I click on "post", the tweet is posted in the log, but is cleared immediately. I am not sure why the console cleans itself right after printing out the tweets.toJSON(). I am using node and livereload2 to load the page after saving. I don't think it is livereload as the behavior is the same regardless of livereload running or not.

1. Everything is wrapped in self invoking anonymous jquery function for scoping I think. So that the variables are not exposed at the window level in the DOM.
2. It takes in JQuery variables as the $ sign, so that I can use it inside the function.

Am I reading this correctly?

Thank you for the help !.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Backbone Twitter App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Backbone for twitter </h1>

    <form id="new-tweet">
        <label>Author:</label> <input id="author-name" name="author-name" type="text" />
        <label>Status:</label> <input id="status-update" name="status-update" type="text" />
        <button>Post</button>
    </form>

    <hr/>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function($) {
            var Tweet = Backbone.Model.extend({
                defaults:function(){
                    return {
                        author: '',
                        status: ''
                    }
                }

            });

            var TweetsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: Tweet
            });

            var tweets = new TweetsList();

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#new-tweet').submit(function(ev){
                    console.log('button pressed');
                    var tweet = new Tweet({author: $('#author-name').val(), status: $('#status-update').val()});
                    tweets.add(tweet);
                    console.log(tweets.toJSON());
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the form is being submitted when you click the button, and reloading the page.

In the submit() method, you can call ev.preventDefault() to stop the form from being submitted.

Comment: I have one more question. Do I have to write

(function($) {
}(JQuery)

I thought this would give a local scope to my variables. But on further reading, it is meant to let me use $ without conflict with other libraries. What is the best practice to write java code?

Comment: Like you said, you only need to use (function($) { }(JQuery) when your website has another framework that conflicts with jQuery (like Prototype). That isn't the case here, so you don't need to use it. As for variable scope, any variable you declare inside of the { } block stays local. The only exception is when you declared a variable with the same name in the global scope. You can, however, get around that  by using var thevariable = 18; inside of the { } block.